# Parse the body of attachment in outlook mail with MAPI Python

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com

I am using win32com for parsing emails in my outlook, how can I parse the contents of attachment in mail.

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts
inbox = outlook.Folders(accounts['<Account-Name>'].DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
messages = inbox.Folders['Inbox'].Items
if len(messages) > 0:
   for message2 in messages:
       title = message2.Subject
       if title == '<Title-of-mail>':
          attachment = message2.Attachments.Item(1)
          print(attachment)
          print(message2.Body)
          # print(attachment.Body) //Error
```

I want to get the contents of attachment, not able to find any proper documentation for this. Any help in guiding me to correct direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to retrieve the Inbox using

`accounts['<Account-Name>'].DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

Secondly, looping through all messages in a folder is a terrible idea - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a restriction on the Subject property..

Thirdly, Outlook would not let you directly access attachment contents, you would need to save the attachment as a file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`), and then read the file contents. If you want to access attachment contents directly, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it exposes [Attachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_Attachment.htm) / [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsText` / `AsArray` / `AsStream` properties.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your reply I will try this. Can you suggest one more thing, is it possible to get html or table contents from message body? Body tag is only giving raw data.